# How to center a CPWindow in Cappuccino

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

I'm interested in having a CPWindow (specifically a CPPanel) be centered and auto-sized much like you might do the same for a CPView as follows:

```
[view setAutoresizingMask:CPViewMinXMargin | CPViewMaxXMargin | CPViewMinYMargin | CPViewMaxYMargin];   
[view setCenter:[contentView center]];
```

However CPWindows seem to not have these same methods.

And while we're at it, how do you prevent a CPPanel from being dragged around? Is such a thing even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPWindow (and CPPanel) have a center method.

[aWindow center];

Comment: Oh yes that can be handy too. ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no autoresizing for a window. You can centre a window or a panel within its browser window by simply placing it in the centre of the available size using code such as this:

```
var containerSize = [[aWindow platformWindow] contentBounds].size,
    aSize = [aWindow frame].size,
    targetFrame = CGRectMake((containerSize.width - aSize.width) / 2.0, (containerSize.height - aSize.height) / 2.0, aSize.width, aSize.height);

[aWindow setFrame:targetFrame display:YES animate:NO];
```

From there on you can update it to stay in the centre whenever the platform window resizes. Listen for `CPWindowDidResizeNotification` notifications sent by `[aWindow platformWindow]`.

I can't think of an easy way to prevent a window from being dragged around short of removing its titlebar by creating it with the `CPBorderlessWindowMask` mask.